# How to Set Consistent Labels Using Geom_bar and Facet_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, geom-bar, facet-grid

I am making some harvest plots to show the risk of bias and direction of effect for outcomes in a number of studies. I am trying to do this using `geom_bar` and `facet_grid`.

My problems: although I have set the labels (which are numbers to represent the studies I am showing) using `hjust` and `vjust`, where the study numbers are adjacent (e.g. 13, 14) the labels do not centre but instead go left and right aligned inside the bar. In addition, I cannot seem to set equal spacing between the bars so that study numbers 13 and 14 are nearly overlapping but 26 and 30 are very far apart.

(Note, the plot does not contain all numbers 1-30 as only a subset are being plotted.)

I would like study number centred in each bar with equal spacing between bars in the same grid.

Here is a screenshot of the output from the code below:

[image: from https://pasteboard.co/IxdyGhP.png]

I think my error is related to how I have set the positioning. I have replaced the numbered labels with words to see if the numbers are dictating position and spacing but the same problem occurred. My code is pasted below.

```
df_CE <- data.frame(StudyNumber = c(1,2,13,14,26,30), 
                    Qual_num = c(60,20,40,40,60,60), 
                    ROB = c("High", "Moderate", "Low"), 
                    Reviewer_effect = c("Intervention", "Intervention", "No Effect", 
                                        "No Effect", "Control", "Control"))

ggplot(df_CE, aes(x=StudyNumber, y=Qual_num, fill=ROB)) +
  geom_bar(aes(width = 3), stat="identity", 
           position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single")) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=df_CE$Qual_num, linetype="solid", color = "black") +
  facet_grid(~Reviewer_effect) + 
  xlab('') + ylab('') +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=NULL) +
  ggtitle("title of plot") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("red", "orange", "green"))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5,face="bold"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size=11, face="bold"), 
        axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold"),
        strip.text = element_text(face="bold"),
        legend.text=element_text(face="bold"),
        legend.title = element_text(face="bold"), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=11, face="bold"), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=11,face="bold")) +  
  geom_text(aes(label=StudyNumber), position=position_dodge(width=1), 
            vjust=2,hjust=0.5, size=4) +
  scale_x_discrete(label=df_CE$Letter) +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Risk of Bias"))
```

Comment: You said you have a screenshot: Is it a screenshot of how the plot actually should look like?

In this case, you can use image-hosting websites like:

https://pasteboard.co/

And then post your question together with the link; it would be easier for others to help you.

Comment: Thanks it's a screenshot of the plot rigght now with misplaced labels and spacing. I have uploaded as suggested. Thank you - https://pasteboard.co/IxdyGhP.png

Comment: Hi, letter should be StudyNumber, but really it doesn't matter which I put, the issue is the same. For the x scale, I don't want to display an x axis so could manipulate x values as needed to get even spacing so long as they could be labelled with the correct number. I don't understand how this would create a bigger distanc ethough, surely if it was continuous all would be close together?